# What is the best way to test if a file exists without knowing which file extension a Craft install is using for templates?

Tags: plugin-development, filesystem

Craft allows users to use whatever template extension they prefer: `.html` or `.twig` or something custom.

We can check if a file exists like so:

```
IOHelper::fileExists($filePath)
```

Is there any way to know which extension we want to be testing for?  By default Craft supports both `html` and `twig` in the supported extensions config setting.

Right now, I have the following which feels a bit clunky:

```
foreach (craft()->config->get('defaultTemplateExtensions') as $extension) 
{
    if (IOHelper::fileExists($template . "." . $extension)) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly how I'd do it.

It doesn't make much sense, but there's nothing stopping a user from having both extensions for a template like:

```
/index.html
/index.twig
```

And your existing code would cover both cases.